# ios can't change corner radius for image in cellforrowatindexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I am trying to round the corners of an image in cellforrowatindexpath like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSString *identifiers = _identifiers[indexPath.row];

    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"bronze"]){
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bronze.png"];
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }



    return cell;
}
```

However, this doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your goal? To draw an outline around the image, (as you would gust if you used Michael's suggestion of setting a borderWidth and borderColor) or are you trying to crop away the corners of the image?

Comment: i'm trying to crop away the corners and make a circle of the image.  This works other places in my code, just not in celforrow

Comment: have you put a breakpoint into the `if`? are you sure the code is actually executed? To which actual value is the cornerRadius set? If you put `NSLog(@"in bronze. radius=%.1f", (float)(cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2));` into the if, what does it print?

Comment: What does your question have to do with Cocoa?

Comment: @ElTomato yes, it should be cocoa-touch instead...

Comment: [cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES]

Answer (score 1):

Try, right after you set your image, calling:

```
[cell layoutSubviews];
```

I don't think that this is the best way to do it, but it is a hack that will work.
This has been tested.

EDIT (for clarity):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSString *identifiers = _identifiers[indexPath.row];

    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"bronze"]){
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bronze.png"];
        [cell layoutSubviews];
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(cell.imageView.frame) / 2;
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Defensive and abrupt much? Should I just start bowing to the almighty Michael now? You should consider checking your ego at the door. Your answer may be correct, and mine may be incorrect, but no need to comment the way you just did. Frankly, the OP may not want a border. Rounding the corners does not REQUIRE a border.

Comment: tried it, doesn't work... because: `-layoutSubviews` is a no-op if the frame is still `CGRectZero`

Comment: Actually, @Michael, you may want to check the frame again. If you call layoutSubviews AFTER setting the image, the frame is now set.

You ALSO have to check to make sure that your cellStyle is set to UITableViewCellStyleDefault as well, or else the image view will be nil.

Answer (score 0):

The imageView has a frame of (0,0,0,0) at this point. So `cell.imageView.frame.size.width` is 0. Therefore, your code sets the cornerRadius to 0 again, which is a no-op.

you could hardcode the value for cornerRadius or you could sublass the table view cell and override -layoutSubviews